# load file using jQuery, count elements of class and set interval ratio

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I am trying to achieve is to load a file, count it's class elements, then display it for the duration of (2sec * no of elements).

Now I can load that file using jQuery:

```
function load() {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    // load my file
    $('#content').load('phpScripts/someFile.php');
  });

  // count items
  i = $('.displayItem').length;
}
```

Then display items using interval

```
setInterval(load, i*2000);
```

but i doesn't exist in this scope (I thought I have declared it global);

then I have tried to use ajax:

```
function start() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "phpScripts/infoScreenContent.php", 
            dataType: 'html', 
            success: function(data) {
              $("#content").html(data);

              i = $('.displayItem').length;
              alert(i); 

            }
        });     

    });
    //  return i;  
}

start();
```

Now that I = which is the count of my element works inside the function, but I need to passed it to another function which is

```
setInterval(start, i*2000);
```

But i=0;

I have tried to return this like I would in PHP but it does not work.

I would appreciate for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code passed in the first argument of `$(document).ready(...)` function will only execute when the document finishes loading. So in your first example, when you call `setInterval(load, ...)`, you're saying every i * 2000 ms: "When the document finishes loading, load `'phpScripts/someFile.php'` to `$('#content')`". But the document only finishes loading once, right?

So that's your first problem - the code to load more content will only execute once.

Now with `setInterval`, once you start it it goes on forever at the same interval. You can't adjust it by changing the value of `i`. Why? Because the interval is calculated only once, when you execute the line `setInterval(load, i*2000);`. The *expression* `i*2000` is turned into a *value* which is then passed to the function `setInterval`.

If you want to execute some code with changing delays, you should instead use `setTimeout`. Here is what I mean:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var elementDisplayTime = 500;
  // All functions defined inside this scope will 'see' this variable.

  function loadNext() {
    // Your code for loading new content here
  }

  function clock() {
    // Load next item
    loadNext();

    // See for how long we have to display it
    var count = $('.displayItem').length;

    // Schedule changeover after delay depending on count
    window.setTimeout(clock, count * elementDisplayTime);
  }

  // Start the clock
  clock();
});
```

My related [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rskjsqm3/).